# python flask "from package.module" error

Tags: python, flask

there're an open source forum([flaskbb - github](https://github.com/sh4nks/flaskbb)) writen by flask, they use `from flaskbb.user.models import User` in */flaskbb/user/models.py* to load `User` class .

I was trying to imitate that so my project '*dawntime*' file structure like this:

```
dawntime
    -__init__.py
    -app.py
    -public
        --__init__.py
        --index.py
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from dawntime.public import index
...
```

both `__init__.py` file are empty and I really think it's not important about how the file */dawntime/public/index.py* is, because of an error occured in line 2 of app.py, complier showed this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "app.py", line 2, in 
>           from dawntime.public import index 
>                 ImmportError: No module named dawntime.public

would anyone tell what's wrong with that? tks in advanced

Comment: Does `index.py` import anything from `app.py`? If so you are running into a circular import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.py` is already in the `dawntime` directory, so instead I think you need

`from public import index`